# Unable to access variable outside ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I just started playing with angularJS today and I am a little stumped at why I can only access my variable in a certain area in my code. In the area below the selectbox, which picks a file from an array, the variable {{ fileInfo }} displays fine and my console log shows the value is there, however the value does not display in the second panel - Can anyone explain where I am going wrong, why it does not appear and how to fix it! Here is the HTML I have created, thanks for your time.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="FileInfo">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Files</h3>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline padding-left">

            <select class="form-control padding-left" name="selectedFile" ng-model="fileSelection" ng-change="FileInfo()" ng-options="opt.filename as opt.basename for opt in files">
            </select>
            {{ fileInfo }}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">File Info</h3>
            <br> {{ fileInfo }}
        </div>
```

Comment: set your `ng-controller` (once) on a shared parent. If you declare it twice, they both have its own scope and the changes on the one won't reflect on the other

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I have removed it, but I am still having the same issue, {{ fileInfo }} only displays inside the above area, not the one below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from your question that you want to display `{{fileInfo}}` twice.

I would create a container `div` around both your `div`s and put the `ng-controller` on container `div`.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="controller1>

    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Stuff --> {{fileInfo}} </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- Stuff --> {{fileInfo}} </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this worked! Is this a common way (the correct?) to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, using a controller on a an element creates a `$scope` that binds the view to the data model. What you were doing initially was creating two instances of the controller like @tymeJV pointed out correctly. Thusly, you were creating two different scopes, one of which does not know about `fileInfo`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 *instances* of the `FileInfo` controller. Controllers are not shared just because you've declared them twice in the HTML. Each controller instance has its own scope.

Comment: Thanks, but after removing it I still seem to have the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Having two controllers that way is asking for trouble. You are probably better off using the so called controller as syntax. This way angular knows to which controller you are binding. Like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="FileInfo as ctrl1">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Files</h3>
    </div>
<form class="form-inline padding-left"> 

<select class="form-control padding-left" name="selectedFile" ng-model="ctrl1.fileSelection" ng-change="ctrl1.FileInfo()"  ng-options="opt.filename as opt.basename for opt in ctrl1.files">
</select>
{{ ctrl1.fileInfo }}
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="FileInfo as ctrl2">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">File Info</h3><br>
                    {{ ctrl2.fileInfo }}
  </div>
```

Be ware that if you use this strategy then on your controller you no longer set up your variables on the **$scope** object but on **this** so instead of $scope.fileInfo you simply do this.fileInfo

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me either, thanks for your help though!

Comment: It's not true that you have to set variables on `this` when using "controller as" syntax. You can stil set variables on `$scope` and use it without controller alias. Check this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zDVs9AJV0PdX2IJXpp58?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

After your edit you set controller once - that's good. But controller works only within `<element>` where it is declared. Your second `{{fileInfo}}` is outside `<div ng-controller="FileInfo">` element. You have to declare `ng-controller` in a `<div>` element which contains both `{{fileInfo}}`.

```
<div ng-controller="FileInfo">
    <div>
        <div>
            {{fileInfo}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{fileInfo}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More importantly the 2 instances have separate scopes.

```
 <div ng-controller="FileInfo">
  first scope:
  {{value}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="FileInfo">
  second scope:
  {{value}}
</div>
```

A quick plunker showing that ng-controller creates separate scopes.
https://plnkr.co/edit/BUuTPP3qTW9HE0jxI1C6?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, the plunker is a good visual aid to see what is going on.